# Can we increase "wait Until" plugin default time in cypress which is 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, java, automation, frontend, cypress

Actually when i use plugin of wait Until in cypress it allow only 5 seconds to wait by default but when if within 5 second if it doesnt find any element it give exception .So i wanted to know that can we increase its timing or not .If we can than how we can do it?

install the plugin.

npm i -D cypress-wait-until
install wait until plugin

Import the following lines in the command.js and the e2e.js file.

import 'cypress-wait-until';
require('cypress-wait-until')

Syntax:
cy.waitUntil(()=> //any cypress commands goes here to wait for)

Answer (score 0):

`cy.waitUntil` has an [optional objects parameter, where you can pass in additional arguments to the command.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until#arguments) This parameter is in the second position, and could be used in your case like so:

```js
cy.waitUntil(() => {
  // cypress code
}, {
  timeout: 10000 // or another value, in milliseconds, to change the timeout
});
```